# Export CSV Data MVC 4 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-csv

Web Application's page retrieves data from MSSQL tables based on certain criteria.

At times data **exceeds more than 1 million lines**.

Worst case data is bind with MVC DataGrid in a minute or so.

There is option provided to download the data in CSV format after data is loaded in the grid.

If user clicks on download the **CSV takes lots of time to be created / downloaded on client's machine**.

Please let me know **what is efficient way to create a CSV file**?

I want that download to be initiated in separate tab or there should be some better way to retrieve such huge data?

Comment: Not sure, but you can achieve this by two ways.
1)divide your result into multiple threads and let each and individual thread to perform some of the records. i.e. if you have 1000 records to read, create 10 threads and assign each thread to read 100 lines.
2)divide the results into multiple threads, assign each thread to generate the files and after that merge those files.

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that you use now to convert your 'raw' data into JSON format.